# How to API integration in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, getserversideprops

I am using this API, https://api.xmltime.com/holidays?accesskey=dYjG8ztthf&secretkey=veUV06dNmrnp7bbaYq0u&version=3&country=ro&year=2021&lang=en

The API is running in my local PC - `https://localhost:5001/api/holiday?&country=ro&year=2021`

I tried to integrate API in my nextjs App. But I did not the data

interface.ts

```
export interface GetAllHolidaysData {
  version: number;
  billing: Billing;
  holidays: Holidays[];
}

export interface Billing {
  credits: number;
}

export interface Holidays {
  id: number;
  urlid: string;
  url: string;
  country: Country;
  name: Name[];
  oneliner: Oneliner[];
  type: string[];
  subtype: Object;
  date: Date;
  uid: string;
}

export interface Country {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

export interface Name {
  lang: string;
  text: string;
}
export interface Oneliner {
  lang: string;
  text: string;
}
export interface Date {
  iso: string;
  datetime: Datetime;
}
export interface Datetime {
  year: number;
  month: number;
  day: number;
}
```

index.ts

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  let country = "ro";
  let year = 2021;

  try {
    const { data } = await GetAllHolidays(country, year);

    console.log("try");
  } catch {
   catch(error) { console.log(error); }   // error message printed in console
  }

  return {
    props: {
      holidays: [],
    },
  };
};
```

api.ts

```
import axios from "axios";
import { GetAllHolidaysData } from "../interfaces/GetAllHolidaysData";

const http = axios.create({ baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API });

export const GetAllHolidays = (country: string, year: number) => {
  return http.get<GetAllHolidaysData>(
    "/holiday?&country=ro&year=2021"

  );
};
```

env.local

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API=https://localhost:5001/api
```

**In console error is printed as output,
What is the mistake i did?**

Error message

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at (holidays/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (holidays-front-end/calendar-holidays/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (holidays-front-end/calendar-holidays/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:269:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:377:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:470:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1312:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  config: {
    url: '/holiday?&country=ro&year=2021',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.4'
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: 0,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    _closed: false,
    socket: Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'localhost',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: null,
      _server: null,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 11589,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    _header: 'GET /holiday?&country=ro&year=2021 HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/0.21.4\r\n' +
      'Host: localhost\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 80,
      protocol: 'http:',
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
      sockets: [Object: null prototype],
      freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'GET',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    path: '/holiday?&country=ro&year=2021',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [Socket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      rawTrailers: [],
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 404,
      statusMessage: 'Not Found',
      client: [Socket],
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'http:/holiday?&country=ro&year=2021',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 10,
      [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
      [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'localhost',
    protocol: 'http:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 0,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'http:/holiday?&country=ro&year=2021',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    }
  },
  response: {
    status: 404,
    statusText: 'Not Found',
    headers: {
      date: 'Mon, 27 Sep 2021 07:15:00 GMT',
      server: 'Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)',
      'content-length': '271',
      connection: 'close',
      'content-type': 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'
    },
    config: {
      url: '/holiday?&country=ro&year=2021',
      method: 'get',
      headers: [Object],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      transitional: [Object],
      data: undefined
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: [Socket],
      _header: 'GET /holiday?&country=ro&year=2021 HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.21.4\r\n' +
        'Host: localhost\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/holiday?&country=ro&year=2021',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'localhost',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    data: '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">\n' +
      '<html><head>\n' +
      '<title>404 Not Found</title>\n' +
      '</head><body>\n' +
      '<h1>Not Found</h1>\n' +
      '<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>\n' +
      '<hr>\n' +
      '<address>Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>\n' +
      '</body></html>\n'
  },
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

Comment: Can you log the error the `catch` is catching? What's the error?

Comment: @juliomalves It goes to catch How to find the error?

Comment: `catch` accepts an `error` param, just add it and log the error inside the block, i.e. `catch(error) { console.log(error); }`.

Comment: In console, I got this `responseUrl: 'http:/holiday?&country=ro&year=2021', `. I guess it sholud be `https://localhost:5001/api/holiday?&country=ro&year=2021`.. What is wrong in my code. Why `baseURL` did not connect with `/holiday?&country=ro&year=2021',`

Comment: Can you please add the full error message to your question?

Comment: @juliomalves i have updated my question with error message.

Comment: If you log `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API` to the console what does it return? Is your env file actually named `env.local`? It needs to be `.env.local` to be picked up by Next.js.

Comment: @juliomalves yes. I save the file as `env.local`. Thank you . Now I changed to `.env.local`. But again I got error `Error: self signed certificate` this error